# Изучение SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных

В связи со сменой работы нужно познакомиться с SQL. До этого опыта работы с SQL и бд не было. На работе используется СУБД `Oracle`. Поискав в интернете наткнулся на книгу Мартина Грабера по sql. Там описывается ansi sql. А в оракле используется `pl/sql`. Но пишут, что книга грабера как раз для начинающих. Можно ли с нее начинать знакомство `sql` или лучше взять литературу по `pl/sql`?

Answer (score 4):

[Интерактивный учебник](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/content.html) (Oracle пока фрагментами).

[Здесь](http://sql-ex.ru/exercises/index.php?act=learn) вы можете выбрать Oracle для освоения SQL на практике.

Answer (score 3):

Вы для себя разделите, чему хотите обучится: языку SQL или особенностям конкретной СУБД. Имхо, полезнее учиться самому SQL, так как все нюансыдля определенной СУБД легко гуглятся.

Кроме того, для понимания работы БД необходимо иметь представление о структуре хранящихся в БД данных, к чему SQL как язык не имеет отношения.

[Здесь](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/books/category_11.html) несколько полезных книг.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала изучите понятия БД, СУБД, работа и структура БД, потом приступайте к SQL исследуйте его семантику и логику. После чего как вы уверенно будете писать запросы, можно переходить к PL/SQL.

PL/SQL - это язык программирования, имеющий свою логику и операторы, это на порядок сложнее, чем стандартный SQL. Потому изучайте последовательно и будет вам успех. Советую книгу *Кристофера Аллена "101 ORACLE PL/SQL"*  доходчиво объясняется все от простейших команд до настоящего программирования.

Также рекомендую ссылку по ораклу: [Первые шаги](http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/oracle1.html)